# What is the use of ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, queue

I am working in bluetooth in android kotlin. I found this [blessed library](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android-coroutines) and this class [BluetoothPeripheral](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android-coroutines/blob/main/blessed/src/main/java/com/welie/blessed/BluetoothPeripheral.kt) is using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. I don't understand what is the use of

```
private val commandQueue: Queue<Runnable> = ConcurrentLinkedQueue()
```

I am looking this [enqueue](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android-coroutines/blob/678b4ebeb249d65382790ba3eb8f0f0aaf132459/blessed/src/main/java/com/welie/blessed/BluetoothPeripheral.kt#L1424) function and I cannot understand the use case in here. what the author trying to achieved in here?

This [enqueue](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android-coroutines/blob/678b4ebeb249d65382790ba3eb8f0f0aaf132459/blessed/src/main/java/com/welie/blessed/BluetoothPeripheral.kt#L1424) function calls in different place i.e. [readCharacteristic](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android-coroutines/blob/678b4ebeb249d65382790ba3eb8f0f0aaf132459/blessed/src/main/java/com/welie/blessed/BluetoothPeripheral.kt#L822) what is the use case in this function?

Thanks

Comment: Which part is not clear to you? "enqueue" keyword and the documentation for `nextCommand()` explain what is going on there. We need to execute commands sequentially, so they are enqueued.

Comment: I don't understand why we need to `enqueue` ? `enqueue` means is adding a item in queue?

Comment: We can only process one command at a time. We use a queue, so if we request a command before the previous finished processing, we only add it to the queue, to be processed after the first one.

Comment: @broot perfect explanation. So is  `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is best options to use in bluetooth case ?

Answer (score 1):

Building on @broot's comment:

1. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is part of the `java.util.concurrent` package which is all about collections that are thread-safe
2. A `Queue` is a kind of collection that is designed for efficient adding and removal.  Typically they offer First In First Out.
3. If you have an application that is dealing with a high throughput of tasks, *producers* put items in a queue and *consumers* take them.  Depending which is faster, you may have more producer threads than consumer threads, or the other way around.  You achieve process isolation by using a thread-safe queue, such as `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`
4. Some Queue implementations have bounded capacity, but a queue like `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is based on a Linked List so typically have have far greater capacity, but mean that some operations, such as search might perform less well.
5. There is also a `Dequeue` which is a `Queue` that you can remove items easily from both ends.

I have no idea what the Bluetooth application is about and why it needs `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` so I cannot comment on whether it is the "best options to use in bluetooth case"